# How can i use EditText to get a parameter in doInbackGround (AsyncTask)?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to use 3 edit texts to get (id, name, family) in my URL. I have already made a Rest web service and now I want to use socket in my Android app. Below is my code which keeps getting an error. What did I miss?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
    public void ok (View view){
        Havij havij = new Havij();
        havij.execute();
    }
    public class Havij extends AsyncTask{
        String name="";
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects)  {

            String str1 = (String) objects[0];
            String str2 = (String) objects[1];
            String str3 = (String) objects[2];
            try {
                URL url =new URL("http://192.168.1.100:8083/rest/pm/rp?id=&name=&family="+str1+str2+str3);
                URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                int ascii = inputStream.read();
                String json = "";
                while (ascii !=-1){
                    json += (char) ascii;
                    ascii = inputStream.read();
                }
                inputStream.close();
                JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) new JSONParser().parse(json);
                for (Object o : jsonArray) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) o;
                    name =name+jsonObject.get("name")+ " ";
                }
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return name;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
            EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            execute(editText1.getText().toString(),editText2.getText().toString(),editText3.getText().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post your error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void ok (View view){
     EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
     EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
     EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
     Havij havij = new Havij();
     havij.execute(editText1.getText().toString(),editText2.getText().toString(),editText3.getText().toString());
}
```

You need to send the `strings` when you call execute in the beginning.
In the question you are calling in `postExecute`.
That method is called *after* background task is finished.
Check [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for information on `AsyncTask`

Your url should be

```
http://192.168.1.100:8083/rest/pm/rp?id="+str1+"&name="+str2+"&family="+str3
```

Comment: well the other problem is : when the all the id,name and family values now have been inserted into family field in data base . Whats the problem ?

Comment: I didnt get you? there is still an issue?

Comment: YEs in my URL . when i use str1,str2,str3 all the Strings values are now set as family value . I mean the str1 should be id and str1 = name , str3 =family . but in my data base ,All the 3 str are set as family .

Comment: I even use this one 
URL url =new URL("http://192.168.1.100:8083/rest/pm/rp?id="+str1+"&name"+str2+"family"+str3);
but the name and family values are still null in my data base

Comment: you missed an & after name=str2